# Comparacion de valores mediante php y recibir el resultado en android

Tags: php, android, api, condiciones, update

Tengo el siguiente codigo android para realizar un update de un registro pero al realizar el update quiero que se compare el campo equipo con el valor que ya esta registrado, si el valor que recibe php desde android es igual al registrado en la base de datos entonces realice el update y en caso de que no sea igual entonces que no lo realice el update.

Update.php

```
<?php
$id_reg=$_GET["id_reg"];
$salida=$_GET["salida"];
$equipo=$_GET["equipo"];

$cont=0;
include("cn.php");

$q=mysqli_query($c,"UPDATE tb_registro SET fecha_sal='$salida',sal='Salida' WHERE Id_reg = '$id_reg' AND equipo= '$equipo' ");

if($q){
    echo "Registro insertado exitoso";
}
else{
    echo "Fallo en el registro";
}
?>
```

DetallesRegistro.java

```
public class DetallesRegistros extends AppCompatActivity {

    AsyncHttpClient cliente;

    EditText etNombre,etId,etReloj,etDepartamento,etfecha,etsalida,etequipo,etvalidacion,etpresion;
    Button b;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    Register usuario;

    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "CheckResult", "MissingInflatedId"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalles_registros);
        relacionamosVistas();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
        usuario = (Register) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("usuario");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        }
        Date date = new Date();

        String fecha = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
        }

        etReloj = findViewById(R.id.reloj);
        etNombre = findViewById(R.id.name);
        etequipo = findViewById(R.id.entrega);
        etDepartamento = findViewById(R.id.equipo1);
        etpresion = findViewById(R.id.presion);

        etId = findViewById(R.id.idreg);
        etfecha = findViewById(R.id.area);
        etsalida = findViewById(R.id.retorno);
        etvalidacion = findViewById(R.id.validacion);


        etId.setText(usuario.getId());
        etReloj.setText(usuario.getReloj());
        etNombre.setText(usuario.getNombre());
        etequipo.setText(usuario.getEquipo());
        etDepartamento.setText(usuario.getArea());
        etfecha.setText(usuario.getFecha());
        etsalida.setText(fecha);
        etpresion.setText(usuario.getPresion());


    }

    public void relacionamosVistas(){

        etReloj=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reloj);
        etNombre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        etequipo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.equipo1);
        etDepartamento=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.area);

        etId=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.idreg);
        etfecha=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.entrega);
        etsalida=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.retorno);

        b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
    }

    public void validar(View v){

        final String id_reg=etId.getText().toString();
        final String salida=etsalida.getText().toString();
        final String equipo=etequipo.getText().toString();

        String url="http://172.30.99.136/insertandroid/update.php?id_reg="+id_reg+"&salida="+salida+"&equipo="+equipo;
        RequestQueue servicio= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest respuesta=new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(DetallesRegistros.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error comunicación",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        servicio.add(respuesta);
    }
}
```

Asi tengo la vista al momento de realizar el update pero al momento de realizar el update.

Lo que quiero es que si no hace match lo que se manda con lo que esta registrado entonces me muestre un toast de error, ya que hasta el momento como tengo mi codigo aunque no haga match la informacion me sigue mostrando el `toast` de registro exitoso a pesar de que no se hizo el update me podrian ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es el escenario o error que te sale o sucede?

Comment: El escenario es que por ejemplo en el campo confirmar equipo debe hacer match con el campo Equipo que en la imagen que anexe con mi pregunta es `P8` el que se registro en la `BD` entonces cuando yo presiono el boton guardar el archivo `PHP` hace la comparacion y aunque yo ponga un equipo diferente al que esta registrado me continua arrojando el toast de `Registro Ingresado Correctamente` a pesar de que el `PHP` no realizo el update por que no era el mismo equipo.

Comment: tienes que validar entonces que esta bien; 1 valida que el php este haciendo lo correcto; 2 valida que informacion esta viajando del php hacia la app en respuesta ... y por que la app esta recibiendo algo como un true cuando al parecer segun lo que explicas debio recibir un false ...

Comment: Lo que quiero es como puedo usar el `if` y `else` para desde PHP mostrar un mensaje dependiendo si se hizo o no el match ejemplo si los equipos hicieron match un mensaje de se `registro correctamente` y si no se hizo el match entonces `Equipo Incorrecto`

Comment: Ya hice lo que me comentaste y en mi PHP tengo la consulta `"UPDATE tb_registro SET fecha_sal='$salida',sal='Salida' WHERE Id_reg = '$id_reg' AND equipo= '$equipo' "`, Y como te comento apesar de que la variable `$equipo` es diferente a lo que esta en la `BD` la app android me arroja el mensaje de `Registro Ingresado Correctamente` pero reviso la `BD` y el registro sigue sin modificacion el PHP esta haciendo justo lo que quiereo lo que no se como hacer es como implementar el `IF` y `ELSE` para mostrar diferentes mensajes

Comment: tienes que comunicar los dos sistemas asi como envias datos de android a php tienes que buscar en la documentacion como recirbirlos.

Comment: ademas cuando los recibes intenta primero imprimirlos el logcat para ver que es exactamente lo que recibes ...

Comment: por lo menos si recibes un "false" o "null" en formato string ... disparas el toast de error; si recibes un mensaje como "Se han registrados 123 registros", tomas el texto y lo utilizas dentro del toast ...

Comment: ahora si quieres algo mas avanzado puedes buscar como implementar json en tu request y como recibir datos por json... eso te enseñara los principios de consumo de API

Answer (score -1):

No me gusta tu codigo y me parece que tiene muchos elementos no necesarios, he resumido lo que quieres segun tus comentarios:

```
// Crear una nueva instancia de RequestQueue
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

// Crear una nueva instancia de StringRequest
String url = "http://example.com/script.php";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Procesar la respuesta en formato JSON
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                String result = jsonResponse.getString("result");
                // Mostrar el resultado en un Toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Mostrar un mensaje de error
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al conectarse con el servidor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        // Añadir los parámetros a enviar
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("param1", "value1");
        params.put("param2", "value2");
        return params;
    }
};

// Añadir la solicitud a la cola
queue.add(postRequest);
```

En el PHP debes tener algo asi:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $param1 = $_POST["param1"];
    $param2 = $_POST["param2"];
    // lógica
    $result = "success";
    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

la idea es poder consumir en php los datos que le empujes con tu aplicacion, pero manteniendo la espera de una respuesta ... no he tenido el tiempo de validar el codigo, puede contener errores pero el concepto aplicado esta en la siguiente documentacion: [link](https://www.develou.com/servicio-web-restful-android-php-mysql-json/) y [link](https://www.develou.com/consumir-un-servicio-web-rest-desde-android/) obviamente te lo he resumido.